# How to compare data of two tables transformed in SSIS package

Tags: .net, ssis, ironpython

A table has been ETLed to another table. My task is to verify the data between two tables programmatically.

One of the difficulties I m facing rite now is:
how to use the expression that I can get from, let s say, derived column task and verify with the source and destination.
or in other words, how can I use the expression to work in the code.

Any ideas....highly appreciated

Sagar

Answer (score 2):

Set up a column which holds a CHECKSUM() of each row.  Do a left outer join between the two tables .  If you have any nulls for the right side, you have problems.